# Checking if an input string is a number and in C++ and, if so, converting it to an int (regex?)

Tags: c++, regex, match

I feel like this is a fairly basic question, but I've searched the internet for over an hour and I haven't found the answer.

I'm writing a text interface that takes an input as a string.  If the input string is a number, I want to convert the string to an integer and push it onto a stack that I created.

The code of the text interface is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "textInterface.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

void Interface(){
    Stack stack = Stack();

    string input;

    cout << "Please enter a number or operation";
    cin >> input;


     if (input == "."){
         cout << stack.pop();
     } //this pops the stack

     if (input == "+"){
         int a = stack.pop();
         int b = stack.pop();
         int c = a + b;
         stack.push(c);
     } //pops the first two things off the stack, adds them, and pushes the result

     if (input == "-"){
        int a = stack.pop();
        int b = stack.pop();
        int c = a - b;
        stack.push(c);
     } //pops the first two things off the stack, subtracts them, and pushes the result

     if (input == "*"){
        int a = stack.pop();
        int b = stack.pop();
        int c = a * b;
        stack.push(c);
     } //pops the first two things off the stack, multiplies them, and pushes the result

     if (input == ".s"){
         cout << stack.count();
     } //returns the size of the stack

     if (regex_match(input, "[0-9]")){
         int num;
         stringstream convert(input);
         convert >> num;
         stack.push(num);
     } //This is the part with the error!!! 

}
```

Like I said, I'd like to check if input is a number, and if so, convert the string to an int and push it onto the stack.  I've worked with regular expressions before, but it's been a while and it was in Python (I'm new to C++).  I know my regex_match is not formulated correctly, does anyone have any advice on how to make it correct, or suggestions for resources to read?

Comment: Why not just `std::stoi`? If you're using GCC, regex isn't implemented, but it's quite unnecessary.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: The only problem is that I don't know how to use stoi to check if the string is a number; as far as I know, it's a conversion tool only, useful if I know that the string can infact be converted to an int.

Comment: no matter what u do u dont need to use regex (as the saying goes - you now have 2 problems). If u want to validate it yourself (as an exercise) then look at each char in turn and see if its 0,1,3,... this is easy to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check if it looks like an integer and then convert it to an integer. Rather, convert it to an integer and see if that worked. Use `std::stoi` (or `stol` or `stoll`, depending on how big you expect the number to be.) (in `<string>`): See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

If the string cannot be converted to an integer of the indicated size, an exception will be thrown, so you have to execute that function inside of a `try`. (That style should be familiar if you're a pythonista.)

Also, if there was a number but it didn't occupy the entire string (i.e. trailing garbage), the `size_t` pointed to be the second argument will be set to the index of the first unused character, so if you want to check that the entire string is a number, you should also check to make sure that the returned index is the size of the input string.

If you're uncomfortable with exceptions, even those thrown by the standard library, it's possible to just use underlying standard c functions, `strtol` and friends. Those have a similar interface, but use an arbitrary value return combined with setting `errno` to try to communicate failure. Personally I think the exception interface is less fiddly, but, as always, tastes vary.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this approach given the character of the question. Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases, not for program flow. If you expect to receive an int (say over a network, for instance) stoi is okay. It should only fail if there was noise over the connection and some corruption made converting the number impossible. That's an exceptional situation.

But if you're asking about how to check that a given input is a number, then you are contemplating that it might not be in the normal execution. Trying, catching the exception and trying something else is not exceptional.

Comment: @Kian: I guess that verifies my claim that "tastes vary".

Comment: @Kian But it's a library function that throws the exception. Should we only catch in exceptional circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted your question because I had the same problem and found no obvious solution.
I developped a, somewhat flawed, solution but good enough for common cases. Still it is definitely something that lacks answers when looking from google. So for the sake of humanity knowledge I'm going to post my solution here.

```
bool StringCtr::IsNumeric(bool onlyIntegersYieldTrue /*= false*/, int intRadix /*= 0*/) const
{
    _ASSERT(intRadix == 0 || intRadix >= 2 && intRadix <= 36);

    bool const acceptsFloats = !onlyIntegersYieldTrue;
    bool ok = false;
    if (!Empty())
    {
        char* pEnd = 0;
        long li1;
        li1 = strtol(Cstr(), &pEnd, intRadix);
        ok = ! (li1 == 0L && pEnd == Cstr());
        if (!ok && acceptsFloats)
        {
            double d1;
            d1 = strtod(Cstr(), &pEnd);
            ok = ! (d1 == 0.0 && pEnd == Cstr());
        }
        if (ok && !acceptsFloats)
        {
            ok = ok && !Contains(".");
            ok = ok && !Contains("e");
        }
    }           
    return ok;
}
```

so this is a method of my string class, the other methods called from there are self explanatory enough I believe. This is trying to use standard C tokenizer (strtol) which is able to accept a lot of formats. That is actually something to be real careful about, because for example number starting with 0 will be interpreted as octal base, when using 0 (auto) radix. otherwize it is convenient because it will recognize 0x.. hexa notation pattern, and distinguish between integers and floating points. it should even understand exponent notation e.g "-1.05e12" for example.

Anyways, it depends on the parsing power you really need, what kind of notation convention you think your users will excpect the program to recognize ? And in the end, do not listen to people saying "it is easy, just check `foreach (char c) { ok = c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }` because this is bullshit and obviously not sufficient. What about negative numbers, floating points, and all that I mentioned before ?

cheers !